# Plantuml active bar matching color from Participant

Tags: colors, plantuml

I am making some plantuml diagrams and for any ACTIVE participant I want to show color similar to participant color.  Is there any way to refer color from participant box directly ?

Example code:

```
@startuml

Participant "bar" as bar #aquamarine
Participant "foo" as foo #lightblue
bar -> foo: hello
activate bar #aquamarine
activate foo #lightblue
foo -> bar : data back
deactivate foo
deactivate bar
@enduml

/' Can above statement - bar color #aquamarine be taken from participant "bar" with some config /'
/' Can above statement - foo color #lightblue be taken from participant "foo" with some config /'
```

Image:
[image: Image from example]

=== Adding new information (WORKAROUND FOR NOW)===
I explored lot of docs what best for now I come up is to write some scripting to get atleast basic color based on parameter like below:

```
' ======= SCRIPTING STARTS=========
' defining colors
!$aClr = "#lavender"
!$bClr = "#business"
!$ctClr = "#deepskyblue"

!function clr()
    !return clr("a")
!endfunction

!function clr($p)
    !return %get_variable_value("$"+$p+"Clr")
!endfunction
' ======= SCRIPTING ENDS=========

participant "A" as a clr()
participant "B" as a clr("b")
```

Please suggest if there is better way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
' ======= SCRIPTING STARTS=========
' defining colors
!$aClr = "#lavender"
!$bClr = "#business"
!$ctClr = "#deepskyblue"

!function clr()
    !return clr("a")
!endfunction

!function clr($p)
    !return %get_variable_value("$"+$p+"Clr")
!endfunction

!procedure active($p)
    activate $p clr($p)
!endprocedure
' ======= SCRIPTING ENDS=========

participant "A" as a clr()
participant "B" as b clr("b")

a -> b : hello
active(a)
active(b)
b -> a : data back

deactivate a
deactivate b
```

Comment: hi Pal - I think you made an assumption that every participant would have different color.    One example that I have to draw 4 databases, 5 third party participant and 3 microservices participant which would share colors.  That's where this won't fit.  Please share your thought around it.  Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).